# Erro UPDATE SqLite e PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

```
<?php

   $ip = $_REQUEST['ip'];
   $port = $_REQUEST['port'];

   class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
      function __construct() {
         $this->open('Tracker.db');
      }
   }

   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db) {
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened \n";
   }
   $sql =<<<EOF
      UPDATE Server SET ip, port VALUES('$ip', '$port') WHERE ip='$ip';
EOF;
   $ret = $db->exec($sql);
   if(!$ret) {
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo $db->changes(), " Record updated successfully\n";
   }

   $db->close();
?>
```

O codigo acima pega os valores Ip e Port vindo via GET e faz o UPDATE na base de dados, na mesma base de dados consigo remover e inserir dados...

O erro retornado por ele e :  `near ",": syntax error`

Comment: É reportado um erro de SQL ou no PHP?

Comment: estacreio que o erro  no  SQL